# Can we set query execution time limit at schema level on Autonomous Database Shared?

Tags: oracle, oracle-autonomous-db

I need to set the query execution time limit for a specific schema on Autonomous Database on Shared Infrastructure.

There is a setting on the "Set Resource Management Rules" page under Administration tab of Service Console but it is applied for the complete DB instance, which we do not want to.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that is currently possible.

That would require a modification to the existing (pre-supplied) resource manager plans, and access to DBMS_RESOURCE_MANAGER is blocked on Autonomous.